# Post Box Highlighter - Highlight a post box background

Tags: script, posts

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: a post being highlighted and de-highlighted after a delay]

### About

Post Box Highlighter adds a "highlight" button to every post's action menu that allows one to temprorarily highlight the background of the target post.

Inspired by [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377435) MSE post.

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

Latest version: 0.3.0

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/post-box-highlighter/raw/master/dist/modern/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/post-box-highlighter/raw/master/dist/modern/index.min.user.js)

#### Platform

Version number means "last tested on":

| Chrome | Edge | Explorer | Firefox | Opera |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 100.0.4896.127 | - | - | - | - |

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695)

Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports [on the source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/post-box-highlighter/issues).

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/post-box-highlighter/blob/master/src/index.ts) is written in TypeScript.

Contributions are welcome, you can always [submit a PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/post-box-highlighter/pulls).